# After uninstalling Microk8s, htop commands still shows its process

Tags: kubernetes

I installed microk8s on my ubuntu machine. After that, I uninstalled it. But Since then I can feel that my PC is getting slow each time I run my pc. So I ran `htop` command and saw that microk8s process is still running there. Can't remove those process. Please check my image for better convenience.
My ubuntu version is: 20.04 
[image: Htop Command Result]

Comment: How did you uninstall it?  Have you looked for a service you can stop?

Comment: I tried with `sudo snap remove microk8s`. I just tried killing with pid in sudo previlege, And it stopped the process. But there are several processes of microk8s.

Comment: Are you saying that these processes get restarted after a reboot? If not, try `pkill -f microk8s`. That should kill all processes with `microk8s` in their "command line". See `man pkill` for details.

Comment: Right, they get restarted after a reboot. 
I checked if there is any folder named microk8s in my `var` or `snap` folder, but found nothing like that